# Laravel - get object id from model reference / save array of linked objects

Tags: php, laravel, orm, eloquent

This must be a beginner question but I'm not so sure what is the way to go. 
I'm trying to save several objects in a db linked to a specific object of a different class.

My first idea was to create a method in the model taking an array of IDs in parameter and manually saving each one of them (something like that :

```
class TestScenario extends Model
{
[...]
   public function saveScenario($scripts)
{
      [...]
      ScenarioElement::insert(['test_scenario_id'=>$this->id,'elementary_script_id'=> $scripts[0]]);    
   });  
}
```

So, my first question is : how to get the correct id of the instance of the object represented by the model ? (obviously `$this->id` is not working, and I'm calling this method through something like         `$testScenario->saveScenario($scripts);` in the controller).

As you guessed, I have another model (class ScenarioElement extends Model) - and the relationship between the two, in TestScenario:

```
public function getScenarioElements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ScenarioElement::class)->orderBy('order','asc');
    }
```

So is there another way to save this ?

Thanks for help and inputs!

Answer (score 0):

The proper naming conventions for defining model relationships is like such:

```
class TestScenario extends Model
{
    public function scenarioElements()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(ScenarioElement::class)->orderBy('order','asc');
    }
}
```

and conversely:

```
class ScenarioElement extends Model
{
    public function testScenario()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TestScenario::class);
    }
}
```

On your corresponding database migration for scenario_elements, you would have :

```
$table->integer('test_scenario_id)->unsigned();
$table->foreign('test_scenario_id')->refences('id')->on('test_scenarios');
```